# Chapter decoration

Tags: pdftex, chapters

Please how do I make the following chapter decoration style ?

**EDIT:**
how can I make in the command which creates this style chapters

`\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}`
the word
`Kapitola` the same shape as `Stabilní konfigurace`?
But not vice versa.
 [image]

**THE CODE**

```
\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\topmargin 2mm
\oddsidemargin 10mm
\evensidemargin 10mm
\textwidth 150mm
\textheight 220mm

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage{czech}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{theorem}

%\makeindex

\input{def.tex}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}


\begin{document}

\title{
Práce je zaměřena na koncepty řeąení her \\
$n$ hráčů ve tvaru charakteristické funkce \\
{\bf stabilní konfigurace}, {\bf kernel} a {\bf nukleolus}.}

%\maketitle
%\tableofcontents

%\input{thU.tex}
%\input{th0.tex}

%%\input{th1.tex}

\chapter{Stabilní konfigurace}

\section{Základní definice}
\begin{definice}
Nech» $\NH=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $n \in \N$ je mnoľina {\bf hráčů}.
Podmnoľiny $\NH$ nazýváme {\bf koalice}\index{koalice},
číslo $v(S)$ nazýváme {\bf výhra} koalice $S$.
Hra\index{hra} ve tvaru~{\bf charakteristické funkce} je ($\NH,\,v$),
kde $v\!:2^{\NH}\rightarrow\R$ splňuje %{\bf personálnost}\index{personálnost}
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item
$v(\emptyset)=0$ a %-- %{\bf personálnost}\index{personálnost}
%\item
$$S,T \subseteq\NH,\,S \cap T=\emptyset \Longrightarrow v(S)+v(T)\ge v(S \cup T).$$
%      -- {\bf superaditivita \index{superaditivita}}
%\end{enumerate}
\end{definice}

\begin{definice}
Nech» $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \R^n$, $S\subseteq\NH$. Píąeme $x(S)$ místo
$\sum_{i \in S}{x_i}$.
Rozklad $\T$ mnoľiny $\NH$ nazýváme {\bf koaliční struktura}\index{koaliční struktura}.
$(x,\T)$ je {\bf platební konfigurace}\index{platební konfigurace}, jestliľe
$x$ splňuje

\begin{enumerate}
\item $x(T)=v(T)$ pro $T \in \T$ -- {\bf koaliční racionálnost}\index{koaliční racionálnost}
\item $x_i\ge v(\{i\})$ pro $i \in \NH$ -- {\bf individuální racionálnost}\index{individuální racionálnost}
\end{enumerate}
\end{definice}


%\input{th2.tex}
%\input{th3.tex}
%\input{th4.tex}


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{all}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

**def.tex**

```
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape} \newtheorem{definice}{Definice}}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape} \newtheorem{lema}[definice]{Lemma}}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape} \newtheorem{veta}[definice]{Věta}}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape} \newtheorem{priklad}[definice]{Příklad}}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape} \newtheorem{dus}[definice]{Důsledek}}

\newcommand\duk{{\sc Důkaz.\ \ }}

\newfont{\mat}{msbm10}

\newcommand\NH{N}

\newcommand\NC{\mathcal N}
\newcommand\KE{\mathcal K}


\newcommand\BX{\mathbf X}

\newcommand\x{\tilde{x}}
\renewcommand\xi{\tilde{x_i}}
\newcommand\xj{\tilde{x_j}}
\newcommand\xl{\tilde{x_l}}


\renewcommand\S{\mathcal S}

\renewcommand\L{\mathcal L}

\newcommand\B{\mathcal B}
\newcommand\T{\mathcal T}
\newcommand\C{\mathcal C}
\newcommand\U{\mathcal U}
\newcommand\V{\mathcal V}
\newcommand\M{\mathcal M}

\newcommand\Skl{\mathcal S_{kl}}
\newcommand\Slk{\mathcal S_{lk}}

\newcommand\Sij{\mathcal S_{ij}}
\newcommand\Sji{\mathcal S_{ji}}


\newcommand\Ekl{\mathcal E_{kl}}
\newcommand\Elk{\mathcal E_{lk}}

\newcommand\N{\mbox{\mat N}}
\newcommand\R{\mbox{\mat R}}
```

Comment: See https://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/ for various chapter styles, at least one being similar to yours.

Comment: Please, don't do it: “Kapitola” is in Helvetica, the chapter number in Times and the text is in Computer Modern.

Comment: @egreg You are completely right. Please see my new question in the edited post.

Comment: I don't understand the current question. If A is the same shape as B, B must be the same shape as A, so what does 'not *vice-versa*' mean? In any case, what does the 'same shape' mean? Please provide the code you're using to produce the output shown (which I take it is what you want to change, though I'm not certain).

Comment: @cfr Please see my **EDIT**  A is the same shape as B but not vice versa means that after the change A and B are both computer modern but both are **not** Helvetica.

Comment: So, to state it a bit simpler, you want `\chaptername` to be in CMR.

Comment: @cfr Yes, right Kapitola title should be in CMR. And also the `Stabilní konfigurace` title.

Comment: @cfr I think we need somehow to dig into `\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}` ?

Comment: Something like `\ChNameVar{\fontsize{14}{16}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont}`.

Comment: @cfr I think it works. What about changing `Stabilní konfigurace` part to the same font as `základní definice` ?

Comment: @cfr It seems to me that `Kapitola` is now more like `Stabilní konfigurace` rather than `Základní definice`

Comment: Probably you want `bx` rather than `m`.